# how do I use the line I get from the file in equation

Tags: python, for-loop, twitter

I am processing on json files with python programming. I want to compare the data from json file with the lines in file.txt and get the output according to the result.

what should I replace with filex[0] in the code?

```
filename = 'paf.json'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip():
               tweet = json.loads(line)

file1=open("file.txt","r")
filex=file1.readlines()
for linex in filex:
    lines=linex

for char in tweet:
    if str(tweet['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']) == filex[0]:
        print(str(tweet['created_at']))
    break
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing what the json or the text file looks like & what are you even trying to compare

Comment: Your first loop is simply overwriting `tweet` for each line, so it just gets the last tweet in the file. And the second loop just sets `lines` to the last line in the file. Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: What is `satirlar`?

Comment: @Barmar ı removed satirlar sorry. 
I want the code to replace filex [0]. I want this code to check if the str(tweet['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url']) value in the json file is equal to the line in the file

Comment: There's no need for `for char in tweet`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but I suspect you want to loop through the lines in both files in parallel.

```
with open("paf.json", "r") as json_file, open("file.txt", "r") as text_file:
    for json_line, text_line in zip(json_file, text_file):
        tweet = json.loads(json_line)
        if tweet['entities']['urls'][0]['expanded_url'] == text_line:
            print(tweet['created_at'])
```

This will tell you if line N in the text file matches the URL in line N in the JSON file.